# Explanation of the syntax : : var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

Tags: angularjs, module

Can anyone please explain the following syntax in Angular:

`var app = angular.module("myApp", []);`

Where can i find similar syntax whilst using Angular-CLI

Comment: the code that you have there is for Angular1. the Angular-CLI is for Angular2. Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 3):

`var app` declares a variable which is equal to `angular.module`.

You are declaring the name of an angular module that you'll be using with your site, and its name is "myApp".

You'll be using the name "myApp" with an angular directive to link up to your index page, like this:

`<html ng-app="myApp">`

or maybe

`<body ng-app="myApp">`

This tells the HTML that it will controlled by an Angular module called "myApp".

The `[]);` closed brackets at the end can contain dependent modules - extra resources that can be used in your angular module to help you do what you want to do.

See more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_modules.asp).